# How to merge and get the count of non-matching entries efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have two data frames like as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
source_df = pd.DataFrame({'source_value':['21ABCDE1','22CDEF2','23DEF3','24FGH4']})
client_df = pd.DataFrame({'source_value':['21ABCDE1','29SB','21ABCDE1','29SB','25FG','25FG','31DE','35DE']})
```

What I would like to do is find the number of `source_values` which are present in `client_df` but not present in the `source_df`.

Please note that there can be duplicates in the `client_df` but not in `source_df`

Basically I have to identify them as they are not valid (because they are missing in the parent dataframe which is `source_df`)

I tried the below but it is for matching entries.

```
pd.merge(
    source_df,client_df,
    how="inner",
    on = 'source_value').groupby('source_value').size()
```

How can I elegantly do it for `non-matching` entries because I have several millions of data (At least 10 million records and can go up to 15 million).

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to get the `source_value` from `source_df` as a set and then filter and count values in `client_df`:

```
source_values = set(source_df.source_value.to_list())
client_df.source_value[lambda x: ~x.isin(source_values)].value_counts()

#29SB    2
#25FG    2
#35DE    1
#31DE    1
#Name: source_value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In []: client_df[~client_df.source_value.isin(source_df.source_value)].value_counts()
Out[]:
       source_value
       29SB            2
       25FG            2
       35DE            1
       31DE            1
       dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Left Merge with Indicator to identify ones in client only

```
In[]: merge_df = client_df.merge(source_df, how='left', indicator=True)
      merge_df[merge_df['_merge']=='left_only'].groupby('source_value').size()

Out[]:
    source_value
    25FG    2
    29SB    2
    31DE    1
    35DE    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
client_df.groupby('source_value')['source_value'].count().loc[pd.Index(client_df.source_value).difference(source_df.source_value)]
```